# How to stop Entity Framework 5 from mapping a property to DB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a property called *StatusList* which should not be mapped. In earlier versions the *NotMap* attribute was there but now I can't find it. What is the equivalent of it in EF5?

Answer (score 6):

There's still a `NotMapped` attribute,  but Data annotations have been moved to

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
```

namespace

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could do this on your db context using the fluent api mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(q => q.FullName);
}
```

Or do as Raphael said and add the `NotMapped` attribute to your entity property:

```
public class User {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName { 
        get {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }
    }
```